# Rails overrides data from objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

when i'm trying to edit my Students and change the subjects the have, the last student i edited loses all his subjects... Can Somebody Help me? Example: Added Math to Josh. Added Math and History to Jenny. Josh's subjects are now empty.

```
 #students_controller
 def edit
  @subjects = Subject.all
 end

 def update
  @subjects = Subject.find(subjects_params)
  @subjects.each do |subject|
    @student.subjects << subject
    @student.save
  end
  if @student.update(student_params)
   flash[:success] = "Success"
   redirect_to students_path
  else
   flash[:danger] = "Error"
   render :new
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clearly sure what logic must be implemented, but i think you need to add `subjects_attributes` to `student_params` method. And also add `accept_nested_attributes_for :subjects` in `Student` model

After it you can do something like this

```
def update
  @student.update(student_params)
end
```

This will add needed subjects to selected student. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html more info about nested attributes

Also you can see `simple_nested_form` gem which wraps all nested attributes.